# Trouble with a beginner coding challenge

Tags: c++, std, cin, cout

Write a program that continues to ask the user to enter any number other than 5 until the user enters the number 5.
Then tell the user "Hey! you weren't supposed to enter 5!" and exit the program.

★ Modify the program so that after 10 iterations if the user still hasn't entered 5 will tell the user "Wow, you're more patient then I am, you win." and exit.

★★ Modify the program so that it asks the user to enter any number other than the number equal to the number of times they've been asked to enter a number. (i.e on the first iteration "Please enter any number other than 0" and on the second iteration "Please enter any number other than 1"m etc. etc. The program must behave accordingly exiting when the user enters the number they were asked not to.)

I got most of the program to work. I have it to a point where it asks for a number starting at 0 and going up, it gives the user the patient message after 10 tries, and exits the program if they enter the number they are not supposed to. However if the user inputs the number above what it tells you not to enter, the program exits with no message.

I do not really know what to search to fix this issue. I have however tried to move some things around, and got rid of some redundant variables.

Any hints would be appreciated, please do not give me the answer up front! Here's what I have so far.

```
#include <iostream>


int main()
{
    const int GUESS = 1; // constant for number of tries
    const int PATIENCE = 10; // constant for message at 10 tries
    int UserNum; // player input
    int InputNum = GUESS; // intializes GuessNumber


    // asks for player input
    do
    {
        std::cout << "Enter any number other then "<< InputNum << ": ";
        std::cin >> UserNum;

        // exits program if user inputs the number displayed
        if (UserNum == InputNum)
        {
            std::cout << "Hey! you weren't supposed to enter " << InputNum << "!\n";
        }
        // increase the Guess counter if they dont enter the number displayed
        else if (UserNum != InputNum)
        {
            InputNum++;

        }

        if (InputNum == PATIENCE)
        {
            std::cout << "Wow, you're more patient then I am, you win.\n";
            break;
        }
    } while (UserNum != InputNum);



    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I think the challenge(for 1 star) is about asking user 10 times any number other than 5..?..but u r totally on different way

Comment: Yes I did that successfully,  the 2 star challenge tells you to change it again to increase the number every time you ask, so I have changed the code since then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your problem is in `do while` loop condition

statements are executed first and condition are checked later

for example

`InputNum` is initialized as 1

so if you enter `2` as input for UserNum  , in the `else if` condition ,`InputNum` will be incremented to `2`

when this condition is evaluated

```
 while (UserNum != InputNum)
```

it will be false as `2==2`

loop breaks

**solution**

change `PATIENCE = 11` and use

```
while (1)   
// this will run infinitely but it will break after 10 iteration or when u press the same number which u shouldn't
```

instead of

```
while (UserNum != InputNum)
```

**the full program**

```
#include <iostream>


int main()
{
    const int GUESS = 1; // constant for number of tries
    const int PATIENCE = 11; // constant for message at 10 tries
    int UserNum; // player input
    int InputNum = GUESS; // intializes GuessNumber


                          // asks for player input
    do
    {
        std::cout << "Enter any number other then " << InputNum << ": ";
        std::cin >> UserNum;

        // exits program if user inputs the number displayed
        if (UserNum == InputNum)
        {
            std::cout << "Hey! you weren't supposed to enter " << InputNum << "!\n";
            break;
        }
        // increase the Guess counter if they dont enter the number displayed
        else if (UserNum != InputNum)
        {
            InputNum++;

        }

        if (InputNum == PATIENCE)
        {
            std::cout << "Wow, you're more patient then I am, you win.\n";
            break;
        }
    } while (1);


    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the help explaining why it was failing! I am going to try to figure out how to stop the loop from repeating infinitely.

Comment: so there is still problem??

Comment: No sorry i was still using the solution from before you edited your answer.

Answer (score 0):

Hey try this program it does exactly what you want.

```
 #include <iostream>
    int main ()
    {
      int GUESS = -1;       //loop variable
      const int PATIENCE = 10;  // constant for message at 10 tries
      int InputNum;         // input from user



  std::cout << "PATIENCE Test" << "!\n";


  do
    {
      GUESS++;
      // asks for player's input
      std::cout << "Enter any number other than " << GUESS << ": ";
      std::cin >> InputNum;

      // exits program if user inputs the number displayed
      if (GUESS == InputNum)
    {
      std::
        cout << "Hey! you weren't supposed to enter " << GUESS << "!\n";
      break;
    }
      if (GUESS == PATIENCE)
    {
      std::cout << "Wow, you're more patient then I am, you win.\n";
      break;
    }

    }
  while (GUESS != InputNum);

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Appreciate the help man, but like I said I did not want you to do it for me, just wanted a push in the right direction

Comment: my fault then..I missed that line of not telling the answer upfront.